# Linq join table and select columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a user table as:

```
Id        Name     PermissionId    ActiveId
1         John                1           1
2        Henry                2           2
```

Permission Table

```
Id     Name
1       User
2       SAdmin

Active Table

Id     Name
1      Enable
2      Disable
```

Then I have my entity as:

```
 public class Users
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public int ActiveId { get; set; }
 }
 public class Permission 
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
 }
 public class Active 
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

In my repository I want to join these tables and get all the users data so I am doin this with linq as:

```
public IEnumerable<Users> GetUserData()
{

 var results = from user in _db.users
          join permission in _db.permission on user.PermissionId equals 
 permission.Id      
      join active in _db.active on user.ActiveId equals active.Id;                  

 return results.ToList();
}
```

How can I select certain columns from the tables I also tried with the following :

```
var results = from user in _db.users
          join permission in _db.permission on user.PermissionId equals 
 permission.Id      
         join active in _db.active on user.ActiveId equals active.Id
          select new {Id = user.id, Name = user.name, Permission = 
permission.Name, Active = active.Name};

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous 
type: int id, string name, string permission, string active>>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Users>'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Just make a class UserData with the fields you need.

Comment: So that means I have to need to have almost identical copies of Users. One Users as above and another UserData with the required result

Comment: You can have `User` property in the `UserData` so that you don't have to copy each property of `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you're returning the anonymous type but your method expects an IEnumerable of Users

```
public IEnumerable<Users> GetUserData()
```

in case you need to return the data in another shape, you just need to create a dedicated class for that return type.

should the new shape have almost the same fields as User, and should it make sense for your project, make the new class inherit from User and extend it with the new fields

make sure you remember to [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) though

Answer (score 0):

The method GetUserData expect an IEnumerable of Users type, and the join expression returns an IEnumerable anonymous type, and the compiler can't recognize it is the same kind of Users (even if it has the same properties): that's the problem. After the join you have to cast the result with Users type, in order to create the correct and expected return type. Below you can find an example:

```
var results = from user in _db.users 
join permission in _db.permission 

on user.PermissionId equals permission.Id 
join active in _db.active on user.ActiveId equals active.Id 
select new Users{Id = user.id, Name = user.name, 
Permission = permission.Name, Active = active.Name};`
```

Hope it will help you.